Uniqueness of irreducible decomposition in a Noetherian topological space
Is this how one proves the uniqueness of the irreducible decomposition of a closed set in a noetherian topological space? I could not find a proof online so I tried to formulate a proof. Please let me know if there are errors, or if it is unnecessary convoluted.
(Edit) Original version, adapted version below:
Let $X$ be a closed set in a noetherian topological space. It is known that there exists a finite decomposition of $X$ into irreducible components. That is, a representation $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ where each $X_i$ is closed and irreducible. (I.e. $X_i$ can't be written as the union of two proper closed subsets.) To prove the uniqueness, assume there exists another irreducible decomposition $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^m Y_j$ we assume that both decompositions are minimal, i.e. there exists no $X_k$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i=1, i \neq k}^n X_i$ and analogously for the other decomposition. Remove all irreducible sets that appear in both decompositions to obtain $\bigcup_{i \in I}^n X_i=\bigcup_{j \in J}^m Y_j$ with $\varnothing \neq I \subset \{1, \dots, n\}, \, \varnothing \neq J \subset \{1, \dots, m\}$. For an arbitrary $j \in J$ we have $Y_j \subset \bigcup_{i \in I}^n X_i$ and thus $Y_j = \bigcup_{i \in I}^n (X_i \cap Y_j)$. Since $(X_i \cap Y_j)$ is closed for all $i$ and $Y_j$ is irreducible, it follows that there exists an $i \in I$ such that $Y_j \subsetneqq X_i$. In the same way we find for $X_i$ some $j' \in J$ such that $X_i \subsetneqq Y_j'$ but this is now contradicts the minimality assumption.
Adapted version:
Let $X$ be a closed set in a noetherian topological space. It is known that there exists a finite decomposition of $X$ into irreducible components. That is, a representation $X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ where each $X_i$ is closed and irreducible. (I.e. $X_i$ can't be written as the union of two proper closed subsets.) To prove the uniqueness, assume there exists another irreducible decomposition $X = \bigcup_{j=1}^m Y_j$ we assume that both decompositions are minimal, i.e. there exists no $X_k$ such that $X = \bigcup_{i=1, i \neq k}^n X_i$ and analogously for the other decomposition. For an arbitrary $Y_j$ we have $Y_j \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ and thus $Y_j = \bigcup_{i \in I}^n (X_i \cap Y_j)$. Since $(X_i \cap Y_j)$ is closed for all $i$ and $Y_j$ is irreducible, it follows that there exists an $i$ such that $Y_j \subset X_i$. In the same way we find some $j'$ such that $X_i \subset Y_{j'}$. Due to the minimality assumption no inclusion in $Y_j \subset X_i \subset Y_{j'}$ can be proper, thus it follows $X_i = Y_j$. In this way we find for every $Y_j$ an irreducible component $X_i$ such that $Y_j = X_i$. Again by the minimality assumption this implies that both decompositions are the same.

I don't think this is a great way to do it. How do you know that after removing common sets, you have $\bigcup X_i = \bigcup Y_J$, for instance? What if one of the $X_i$ had some parts that were contained in some of the common components from both decompositions, but no $Y_j$ did? That's at least one spot which deserves another look.
One way I like better is the following, sourced from the Stacks Project's section on irreducible components (ref):

Lemma 004W. Let $X$ be a topological space.

If $T\subset X$ is irreducible, so is its closure.
Any irreducible component of $X$ is closed.
Any irreducible subset of $X$ is contained in an irreducible component of $X$.
Every point of $X$ is contained in some irreducible component of $X$, in other words, $X$ is the union of its irreducible components.

Lemma 02GY. Let $X$ be a topological space and suppose $X=\bigcup_{i=1,\ldots,n} X_i$ where each $X_i$ is an irreducible closed subset of $X$ and no $X_i$ is contained in the union of the other members. Then each $X_i$ is an irreducible component of $X$ and each irreducible component of $X$ is one of the $X_i$.
Proof. Let $Y$ be an irreducible component of $X$. Write $Y=\bigcup_{i=1,\ldots,n} (Y\cap X_i)$ and note each $Y\cap X_i$ is closed in $Y$ since $X_i$ is closed in $X$. By irreducibility of $Y$, we see that $Y$ is equal to one of the $Y\cap X_i$, i.e. $Y\subset X_i$. By maximality of irreducible components we get $Y=X_i$.
Conversely, take one of the $X_i$ and expand it to an irreducible component $Y$, which we have already shown is one of the $X_j$. So $X_i\subset X_j$ and since the original union does not have redundant members, $X_i=X_j$, which is an irreducible component. $\blacksquare$


Thanks for pointing out the error, I tried to adapt my proof.

Say $X= \cup_{i\in I} X_i = \cup_{j \in J} Y_j$, with $X_i \not \subset X_{i'}$ for $i \not = i'$, and same for the $Y_j$'s and all $X_i$, $Y_j$ irreducible, and $I$, $J$ finite. Now since $X_i \subset \cup_{j\in J} Y_j$, and $X_i$ is irreducible, then $X_i \subset Y_{\phi(i)}$, and also $Y_j \subset X_{\psi(j)}$, so $X_i \subset X_{\psi\circ \phi(i)}$, for all $i$, hence $\phi$, $\psi$ are inverse bijections, and $X_i = Y_{\phi(i)}$.
